# NUnit Assert is missing definitions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit

I've installed NUnit (4.0.1) and NUnit3Testadapter (4.5.0) as a NuGet Package in Visual Studio 22.

Wrote my test cases, but I'm getting errors that definitions are missing from the Assert class:

> Error CS0117  'Assert' does not contain a definition for 'AreEqual'
>
> Error CS0117  'Assert' does not contain a definition for 'IsNotEmpty'
>
> Error CS0117  'Assert' does not contain a definition for 'IsTrue'

How can I resolve these?

- Reinstalled the NuGet packages
- Rebuilt the solution
- Cleaned the solution
- Verified that NUnit is compatible with EPPlus

Comment: Use current Nunit syntax? Like `Assert.That(value, Is.EqualTo(expectedValue))`?

Comment: Docu says you might use `ClassicAssert` instead of `Assert` to get old syntax.

Comment: Note that it's now V4, a major (breaking) release.

Comment: You can try updating NUnit and NUnit3Testadapter to the latest versions. In addition, you can also try using ClassicAssert. The ClassicAssert class provides backward compatibility for older tests that used the Assert class in NUnit 2.x.

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, after updating to newest version, ran into same problem.

If you don't want to use the new way of asserting, change your Assert.Something, to ClassicAssert.Something, like:

```
Assert.IsTrue(result);
```

to

```
ClassicAssert.IsTrue(result);
```

If you want to give new syntax a try, use Assert.That instead, like:

```
Assert.That(result);
```

For more information check the docs [new](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/assertions/assertion-models/constraint.html), [classic](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/assertions/assertion-models/classic.html) syntax.

Answer (score 3):

It's a breaking change of NUnit 4.0

Just follow the steps:

1. Convert `using NUnit.Framework;` into both `using NUnit.Framework;` `using NUnit.Framework.Legacy;`
2. Convert `Assert` into `ClassicAssert`.

   1. Convert `Assert.AreEqual` into `ClassicAssert.AreEqual`.
   2. Convert `Assert.True` into `ClassicAssert.True`.
   3. Similar for `IsTrue`, `False`, `IsFalse`, `Greater`, `Less`, ...

Detailed information can be found at:
https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/release-notes/Nunit4.0-MigrationGuide.html

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the inclusion of `using NUnit.Framework.Legacy;`!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are some problems with latest releases of NUnit package. 4.1.0 by me also does not work. I have downgraded NUnit back to 3.13.3 and it all works with again with method AreEqual.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have done so far with version 4.0.1 which is latest and looks something like this.

1. Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null);
2. Assert.That(result, Is.Null);
3. Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(something));
4. Assert.That(result, Is.False);
5. Assert.That(result, Is.True);

You can assert any kind of result using Assert.That()